# Do eigenvectors always form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a $n \times n $ matrix  over $\Bbb R$.

Is it necessary that we should have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues so that they form a basis?

Can you give a proof or counterexample?

How about if you have the same question over complex numbers?

Comment: I don't know if you've learned about diagonalizable matrices yet, but: matrices which have a full set of LI eigenvectors are exactly those which are diagonalizable. Any non-diagonalizable matrix (such as the one Chris Eagle gave) will furnish an example.

Comment: It seems you are asking, in the body of your post: If we want a basis of eigenvectors, do we need to have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors? The answer to this is "yes"; any basis must consist of $n$ linearly independent vectors. But, it is not always the case that an $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @Yobo Most people are probably reading it as "Is there necessarily a basis of eigenvectors?" But David Mitra's right: "Is it necessary... so that ..." literally means what he described. Which meaning did you intend?

Comment: sorry for the confusion : i meant "Is there necessarily a basis of eigenvectors?" and i see now the answer is IFF diagonalizable.. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, of course not. For example, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue, with eigenspace $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Thus there are not enough independent eigenvectors to form a basis.

Comment: You can generalize this by looking at the minimal polynomial. If it is not square-free, there is no Eigenvectorbasis.

Comment: Oh, okay, I read the question wrong. If you want a basis of Eigenvectors, you sure need n linear independent vectors (tautologically). But there is not always a basis of eigenvectors. There is one if and only if the minimal polynomial is square-free and factorizes in linear factors. For a field of characteristic zero or a finite one this means that you have always a basis of eigenvectors over the algebraic closure, as long as the minimal polynomial is square free.

Comment: As for "what about over complex numbers?" you can use this matrix $A$ above over any field to show that $XAX^{-1}$ is never diagonal for any nonsingular $X$, so the same example applies to $\Bbb C$ and whatever other field you like.